# Binding a property from a class to XAML directly

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I was curious as I was learning more on binding with WPF do you HAVE TO set the data context to simply set the {binding path=} of a single property?  I was just curious as I was learning from the MVVM example of code behind and it appears I have a situation I want to bind to something not in the data context of the ViewModel and I would prefer an intermediary class over code behind to reference in a binding.  So could I have yet another class I reference for either a second datacontext or something similar?  Or could I set a resource key and reference the class somehow?  I ultimately want to access a property in a separate class if possible.

EG:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFTestBinding.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:da="clr-namespace:WPFTestBinding.DataAccess"
        xmlns:main="clr-namespace:WPFTestBinding"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Here we go: "/>
            <TextBox x:Name="testtext" />
            <Label Height="50" />
            <!-- CODE BELOW WILL NOT WORK -->
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TestID}" x:Name="testtext2" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I know I can set the value of a TextBox in code behind and it works in the example of a property but it will not for the binding.  Is there a way to do simple binding on the fly for properties from classes?  I have not found a simple example that does this and I was searching online and while learning binding most examples are either very intense sets of settings data contexts or very simple static resource examples.  I was just curious if you could use the {Binding Path=} and extend some other property on the fly to just get the code in the class.

Rest of code is pretty simple:

```
namespace WPFTestBinding.DataAccess
{
    class Test
    {
        public string TestID { get { return "This is my test"; } }
    }
}

 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {    
        public MainWindow()
        {
           InitializeComponent();

           DataAccess.Test t = new Test();

           testtext.Text = t.TestID;  // code behind works easily
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set the DataContext in Xaml like this:

```
<Window xmlns:da="clr-namespace:WPFTestBinding.DataAccess">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <da:Test/>
    <Window.DataContext>

    <TextBox Text="{Binding TestID}"/>
</Window>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  I knew there was a simple method to extend the namespace in the XAML I was missing.

Answer (score 8):

Some points to note:

- The property `TestID` you are trying to bind is read-only, as it only
  has get-accessor. Therefore, Binding should be `OneWay` only.
- Assigning the DataContext: You can assign the instance holding your model such MainViewModel with ICollection<BaseViewModel> property (which would be having all the derived instances in the collection) or directly the model itself (as in your case). As I have done in code below.

**Code**

```
namespace WPFTestBinding.DataAccess
{
    class Test
    {
        public string TestID { get { return "This is my test"; } }
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{    
    public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();

       DataAccess.Test testInstance = new Test();
       this.DataContext = testInstance;
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TestID, Mode=OneWay}" x:Name="txtTestID" />
```

For more refer:

- [MSDN - Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)
- [MSDN - WPF BindingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode.aspx)
- [Code Project - DataContext-in-WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321899/DataContext-in-WPF)
- [SO - What is DataContext for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7262137/what-is-datacontext-for)
- [SO - Difference between Datacontext and ItemSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/801233/difference-betwwen-datacontext-and-itemsource-in-wpf)

Comment: Great points, for my example I was not concerned about having to add a 'set' method to my property but at times it will matter.  Thanks for adding the information on the Mode.  I had looked at the two first links you gave prior but the two links on DataContext you gave are very good.

Answer (score 6):

The data context is not set. The DataBinding doesn't know where to take TestID from. Here is correct code behind:

```c#
namespace WPFTestBinding.DataAccess
{
    class Test
    {
        public string TestID { get { return "This is my test"; } }
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{    
    public MainWindow()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       DataAccess.Test t = new Test();

       DataContext = t;           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - You have to fill the Prop **before** InitializeComponent(); in .cs class.

2 - use this in Window tag : DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"

3 - Label tag : Label Content="{Binding Currency}"