# WPF ComboBox databinding xaml vs. code

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am by no means an expert on WPF so this is probably very simple. I'm trying to bind a List to a combobox. It works in code, it doesn't work in xaml. If I remove the ItemsSource from the constructor, it doesn't work, which is how I know. I thought I had the equivalent in xaml, but apparently it's not.

xaml:

```
    <ComboBox Height="23"
              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
              Margin="146,76,0,0"
              Name="comboBox1"
              VerticalAlignment="Top"
              Width="120"
              ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableActions}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              SelectedValuePath="Name"
              SelectedValue="Replace" />
```

constructor:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        _availableActions = new List<IMapperAction>
                       {
                           new ReplaceAction(),
                           new CollapseAction(),
                           new NewBasedOnAction()
                       };

        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += OnWindowLoaded;

        comboBox1.ItemsSource = AvailableActions;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to set the `DataContext` of the main window:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    _availableActions = new List<IMapperAction>
                   {
                       new ReplaceAction(),
                       new CollapseAction(),
                       new NewBasedOnAction()
                   };

    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    Loaded += OnWindowLoaded;
}
```

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks! Why did it work in code? Because it was pushing the context to the xaml rather than doing it from xaml, which would mean needing a context in which to "talk" to?

Comment: in works in code because you set the itemsource directly, without binding.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested here, you have to set the DataContext.

You can also read this link to know why and when which of the two should be used:

[Why are DataContext and ItemsSource not redundant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793340/who-has-the-best-answer-for-why-datacontext-and-itemssource-are-not-redundant)